# How can I use Schema.org for an actor who works in a theater?

Tags: schema.org

How can I use Schema.org for an actor who works in a theater?
My CV is something like:

- I'm a Person whose name is "Harald Effenberg" and whose jobTitle is "actor".
- In dateCreated "year(1)" I played the character "character(1)" in the CreativeWork "creativework(1)" in the PerformingArtsTheater "performingartstheater(1)", the director was "director(1)".
- In dateCreated "year(2)" I played the character "character(2)" in the CreativeWork "creativework(2)" in the PerformingArtsTheater "performingartstheater(2)", the director was "director(2)".

And so on.

But how can I do this? Movie and TVSeries seem to be CreativeWork where actors play characters and directors direct - that's no problem.
But in TheaterEvent there are no actors and no directors allowed and they are not CreativeWork. It is not possible to workFor a PerformingArtsTheater or to be affiliated with it.

Is it possible that the creators of Schema.org never turned off their TVs and never saw a real theater from within? ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`CreativeWork`](http://schema.org/CreativeWork) is for the work.
[`TheaterEvent`](http://schema.org/TheaterEvent) is for a specific performance, i.e., on a specific date.
[`PerformingArtsTheater`](http://schema.org/PerformingArtsTheater) is for the building.
[`TheaterGroup`](http://schema.org/TheaterGroup) is for the organization/team.

This allows you to make the following statements:

- [`PerformingArtsTheater`](http://schema.org/PerformingArtsTheater) → [`event`](http://schema.org/event) → [`TheaterEvent`](http://schema.org/TheaterEvent)
- [`TheaterEvent`](http://schema.org/TheaterEvent) → [`workPerformed`](http://schema.org/workPerformed) → [`CreativeWork`](http://schema.org/CreativeWork)
- [`TheaterEvent`](http://schema.org/TheaterEvent) → [`performer`](http://schema.org/performer) → [`Person`](http://schema.org/Person)/[`TheaterGroup`](http://schema.org/TheaterGroup)
- [`TheaterEvent`](http://schema.org/TheaterEvent) → [`location`](http://schema.org/location) → [`PerformingArtsTheater`](http://schema.org/PerformingArtsTheater)
- [`TheaterGroup`](http://schema.org/TheaterGroup) → [`employee`](http://schema.org/employee) → [`Person`](http://schema.org/Person)
- [`TheaterGroup`](http://schema.org/TheaterGroup) → [`location`](http://schema.org/location) → [`PerformingArtsTheater`](http://schema.org/PerformingArtsTheater)

So you can’t specify the performer of a work, only of specific performances of this work (which makes sense, I guess). To specify the character you’ve played in a performance, you can use [`PerformanceRole`](http://schema.org/PerformanceRole):

- [`TheaterEvent`](http://schema.org/TheaterEvent) → [`performer`](http://schema.org/performer) → [`PerformanceRole`](http://schema.org/PerformanceRole) → [`performer`](http://schema.org/performer) → [`Person`](http://schema.org/Person),
- where the `PerformanceRole` item specifies the [`characterName`](http://schema.org/characterName).

What is missing:

- The [`director` property](http://schema.org/director) can’t be used on `CreativeWork` (only on more specific types), and there doesn’t seem to be an appropriate property for [`TheaterEvent`](http://schema.org/TheaterEvent).
- You can’t specify a *period* in which you’ve performed in various `TheaterEvent` (you can either specify a specific date, or no date at all).

  Maybe using [`PerformAction`](http://schema.org/PerformAction) can help here. (I’m not sure if such repeated events are an appropriate case for [`startTime`](http://schema.org/startTime)’s "actions that span a period of time".)